# What is the best way to handle my error messages in the rails transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions

I am use Rails 4.1.5 and Ember 1.7.0. And I have a problem is how to send error messages from my server api.

The code like this:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    a.save
    b.update(xxx)
    c.update(xxx)
  end
  return a
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  a.errors.add(:base, e.message)
end
```

If I use `a.errors.add(:base, e.message)` to get the errors message from the `transaction`. The `json` will like this:

```
errors: {base:[RecordInvalid: Name can not be blank]}
```

But I think the error message like this and it is better:

```
errors: {name:[can not be blank]}
```

If I want to get the error like `name:[can not be blank]`, I can write the code like:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    a.save
    b.update(xxx)
    c.update(xxx)
  end
  return a
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  return a
end
```

But it is also have problems. If the b model update have `RecordInvalid` errors, I counld not get b model errors message.

So I do not know how the manage my error message from transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you really want to get all the responses

I guess you can try following

```
@a_response, @b_response, @c_response = '', '', ''
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @a_response = (a.save).error_msgs
    @b_response = (b.update(xxx)).error_msgs
    @c_response = (c.update(xxx)).error_msgs
  end
  
  return "#{@a_response}. #{@b_response}. #{@c_response}. "
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  return "#{e} : #{@a_response}. #{@b_response}. #{@c_response}. "
end
```